# Excluding mobile devices from google analytics traffic with the analytics opt out plugin

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

Ive got a dynamic IP at both my office and at home, this leaves my only option for blocking myself showing up in google analytics the google analytics opt out browser plugin, this works fine when im on my laptop.

But especially now with mobile sites, i need to test them on mobiles and tablets. Is there a browser plugin for mobile and tablets that will exclude that device from google analytics ?

(background : primarily im testing in iOS safari and iOS chrome)